# Безопасность функции pop() у контейнера

Tags: c++, исключения, безопасность, стек

> Трудно сделать безопасной функцию, выполняющую две различных операции.

Далее говорилось, что на основании этого функция `pop()` из класса `std::stack` (или другого контейнера, имеющего pop-возможность) не возвращает значение, которое ликвидируется из контейнера, поскольку оно может *потеряться*, если соответствующий `operator=` или конструктор, принимающий это значение возбудит исключение.

Вопрос: можно ли в `pop(T& value)` сделать параметр `value`, в который будет сохраняться ликвидируемое значение? В таком случае не должно быть потери значения в результате исключения. Будет ли такая реализация безопасной?

Например, такая реализация:

```
template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::pop(T& value)
{
    if (this->m_size != 0)
    {
        value = m_array[m_size - 1];
        --m_size;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Саттер в своей *"Решение сложных задач на С++"* признает это решение безопасным с точки зрения исключений (задача 2.3, стр. 112).

Но это решение он отвергает именно как выполняющее две задачи одновременно, а не как опасное с точки зрения исключений.

Так что ответ на ваш вопрос - да :)

Но! Этот `pop()` **не гарантирует** иное - снятие значения со стека. Если там лежит какой-то мерзкий элемент, который при копировании генерирует исключение - то при наличии отдельных `top()` и `pop()` вы можете получить на него ссылку **не копируя** сам элемент и поработать с ним, а потом `pop()` снять его со стека.

Но ваш `pop()` может просто ничего не суметь сделать и угробить программу вечным исключением :)

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Посмотрю в книге. Просто потребовалось одной безопасной функцией сделать, такая вот вариация контестной задачи. Про снятие, это уже другой разговор.